# the system network services are not compatible with this version

Tags: 13.04

When  I try to change my MAC adress from terminal the I restarted pc the the wi fi disabled and I can not open it then I open network

The it popup this message

```
The system network Services Are Not Compatible With This Version
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to change mac address on nic is:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx represent mac address. No need to restart pc.
If you wish to setup mac address when pc start put this comand in rc.local

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

```
 ifconfig eth0 down &&
 ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx &&
 ifconfig eth0 up &&
```

then press ctrl+O for write and ctrl+X for close.
Restart pc and will be work.